# Scala: How to load environment variables into Application.conf using scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, pureconfig

I have a ConfigLoader which I'm pretty sure works fine. I suspect I am not using application.conf file correctly or perhaps my directory containing the prd.env and dev.env is not in the correct place.

What I expect to happen:

I when I enter `sbt run` the ConfigLoader reads the application.conf file, sees there are variables within that file. Then checks if prd.env or dev.env depending on which environment it is in and then finally loads the variables. I want this so I can have a different database for dev and prd.

1. I have not idea how it would find the Meta directory which contains the prd.env and dev.env (see image).
2. I have no idea how it would be able to tell whether if the environment is in dev or prd.
3. The goal is to now look towards deploying this app, which is why I need these environment variables to work.

I really appreciate all the help but please try and detail your answers because I am really stuck and short answers often assume I know more than I do. Thanks :)

Tech stack incase relevant:

- HTTP4S,
- CATS,
- Doobie,
- PostgreSQL

**application.conf file below:**

```
appone {
    environment = ${ENV}

    server-config {
      url = ${?BASE_URL}
      host = "0.0.0.0"
      port = 8080
    }

    db-config {
        driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        url = ${?DATABASE_URL}
        user = ${?APPONE_POSTGRES_USER}
        password = ${?PASSWORD}
        connection-threads = 4
    }
}
```

**Meta/dev.env file (I also have a Meta/prd.env but have shown it here due to contents)**

```
ENV=dev

BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080/
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5400/bookswapdb
APPONE_POSTGRES_USER=su
PASSWORD=password
```

**LoadConfig file below:**

```
package com.fullstackryan.appone.config

import cats.ApplicativeError
import cats.implicits._
import pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderException
import pureconfig.{ConfigReader, ConfigSource, Derivation}
import shapeless.the

trait LoadConfig[F[_], TConfig] {
  def load: F[TConfig]
}

object LoadConfig {
  def load[F[_], TConfig](implicit loadConfig: LoadConfig[F, TConfig]): F[TConfig] =
    the[LoadConfig[F, TConfig]].load

  def apply[F[_], TConfig](
                            implicit reader: Derivation[ConfigReader[TConfig]], ae: ApplicativeError[F, Throwable]
                          ): LoadConfig[F, TConfig] =
    new LoadConfig[F, TConfig] {
      def load: F[TConfig] = ApplicativeError[F, Throwable].fromEither {
        ConfigSource.default
          .at("appone")
          .load[TConfig]
          .leftMap(ConfigReaderException(_))
      }
    }

}
```

**error**

```
pureconfig.error.ConfigReaderException: Cannot convert configuration to a scala.runtime.Nothing$. Failures are:
  at 'appone.db-config':
    - (application.conf @ jar:file:/Users/ryanmcavoy/fullStackRyan/appone/target/bg-jobs/sbt_3cc4b1f5/job-11/target/419ddc2c/5befcb57/appone_2.13-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/application.conf: 10) Key not found: 'url'.
    - (application.conf @ jar:file:/Users/ryanmcavoy/fullStackRyan/appone/target/bg-jobs/sbt_3cc4b1f5/job-11/target/419ddc2c/5befcb57/appone_2.13-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/application.conf: 10) Key not found: 'username'.
    - (application.conf @ jar:file:/Users/ryanmcavoy/fullStackRyan/appone/target/bg-jobs/sbt_3cc4b1f5/job-11/target/419ddc2c/5befcb57/appone_2.13-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/application.conf: 10) Key not found: 'pool-size'.

        at com.fullstackryan.appone.config.LoadConfig$$anon$1.$anonfun$load$1(LoadConfig.scala:25)
        at cats.syntax.EitherOps$.leftMap$extension(either.scala:172)
        at com.fullstackryan.appone.config.LoadConfig$$anon$1.load(LoadConfig.scala:25)
        at com.fullstackryan.appone.server.ApponeServer$.$anonfun$stream$1(ApponeServer.scala:32)
        at com.fullstackryan.appone.server.ApponeServer$.$anonfun$stream$1$adapted(ApponeServer.scala:31)
        at fs2.Stream$.$anonfun$flatMap$1(Stream.scala:1188)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$.go$2(Algebra.scala:609)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$.$anonfun$flatMapOutput$1(Algebra.scala:616)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$$anon$1.cont(Algebra.scala:53)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$ViewL$$anon$9$$anon$10.cont(Algebra.scala:242)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$ViewL$.mk(Algebra.scala:231)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$ViewL$.apply(Algebra.scala:220)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC.viewL(Algebra.scala:106)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$.go$1(Algebra.scala:414)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$.$anonfun$compile$8(Algebra.scala:464)
        at fs2.internal.FreeC$.$anonfun$compile$1(Algebra.scala:430)
```

```
addSbtPlugin("io.github.davidgregory084" % "sbt-tpolecat" % "0.1.14")
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10")

addSbtPlugin("au.com.onegeek" % "sbt-dotenv" % "2.1.204")

// deploy heroku
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.heroku" % "sbt-heroku" % "2.1.0")
```

[image]

Comment: It's to complicated. Can you provide the simplest project, that leads to a problem?

Comment: Here is the github repo if that helps? https://github.com/fullStackRyan/appone

Comment: No. Repo is also a big (and than, a complex) project. The solution to the problem is usually achieved by reducing its complexity. Localizing a problem is usually the first step towards solving it.

Comment: Frist, something that is not your app should create those envvars so **pureconfig** could read it, this is usually work of your deployment tooling not of your application. Specially because those are secrets and must not be part of your code nor of your repo, those should be on an encrypted vault and the automatic deployment should read them and inject them into your runtime environment before running the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running via `sbt run`, the environment is set by the shell in which you're running sbt.  Defining a `dev.env` file by itself does nothing.

The mechanism for setting the environment in which sbt is running will vary depending on your shell.

For example if bash is your shell (this is worth trying in other Bourne-compatible shells), prefixing the environment variables with `export`, e.g.:

```
export ENV=dev
```

Then you incorporate the environment variables you've exported from `dev.env` into your bash environment with

```
source meta/dev.env
```

Those environment variables will then be set and thus incorporated into your config for the duration of your shell session (i.e. they'll continue across multiple `sbt run`s until you exit the shell).  If you change `dev.env`, they won't be available until you `source meta/dev.env` again.

Comment: OP is using this sbt plugin https://github.com/mefellows/sbt-dotenv . So, unless OP did not correctly configure their build.sbt, it should work using `sbt run`. Assuming that OP is using `sbt run` to run the project.

Comment: Just checked the project on github, I did not see any configuation related to `dotenv`.

Answer (score 2):

See where the error says `application.conf: Key not found: 'username'`? That means it's looking for some `username` in that `application.conf` file and not finding it. If you look at your `application.conf` file yourself, you can see that indeed there is no setting in there called `username`. There is one called `user`, maybe that's what you had intended?

We also see `Key not found: 'pool-size'`, looks like there's no setting for that either.

Finally, it says `Key not found: 'url'`. There are two `url` keys in your `application.conf`, which means that the code isn't looking in the right part of the config file. Maybe it's looking for `appone.url` when you want it to be looking for `appone.db-config.url`.